# Running install script on Module Installation: How can I set a module chrome programatically?

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, joomla-api, installation

I have created a custom module and I want to change the module chrome to "none".  This can be achieved in the back end, but I would like it as the default behaviour in case others use the module.  I want it to be as simple as possible to work out of the box.

Is there a way to do this automatically?  The XML file does not include this option so I cannot do it in there.

Comment: Hi - your question is a bit unclear, or you might be confused about how things work. With "created a module" you meant to say that you developed a custom one, or just created one of the available ones in the backend. When you say programatically- what you have in mind - and how programatically would be more user friendly than the backend select option? Can you specify/describe what your actual problem is that would be solved programatically?

Comment: @FFrewin thanks for the feedback I updated the question.  My module works in the admin end, and works in the `cpanel` position.  Ideally I would like to set `cpanel` as the position and module chrome to `none` automatically.  I've never seen a module appear with a module position, but I assume there is a way to do this.  Perhaps in the post processing part of install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Updated Answer:

After your explanations I see what you are after.
Indeed you can do this during the installation of your module. Since the module is intented for the backend and you only going to need 1 instance of it, setting the module chrome during the installation does make some sense.

In your module's `install.php` you can update the module that is created during installation with a `postflight` function:

```
function postflight($type, $parent)
{
    // check if it's the first time the module is installed.
    if($type == 'install') 
    {
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $module_name = 'your_module_name';

        // get module id that is created during installation 
        $query = 'SELECT `id`' .
            ' FROM `#__modules`' .
            ' WHERE module = ' . $db->quote($module_name);
        $db->setQuery($query);

        try
        {
            $moduleid = $db->loadResult();
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            $moduleid = '';
        }

        // Do we have a module?
        if (!empty($moduleid) )
        {
            // Get Modules' JTable
            $module = JTable::getInstance('module');

            // Load the module instance by id
            $module->load($moduleid);
            $params = array(
                'style' => 'System-none',
                'cache' => 0
            );

            // Set Module's properties
            $module->set('title', (string) 'This is my title');
            $module->set('position', (string) 'New Position');
            $module->set('params', json_encode($params));

            // Store in the database
            $module->store();
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can find more info about including an installation script with your module:
 [**Creating Simple Module/ Adding Install-unintall-update script.**](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file)

### Initial Answer:

As said in my comment above, it's not clear what you are asking or your actual problem is. So I am going to make a guess that you have developed a module for which you would prefer to not showing anything around it when it's installed and set to show on a module position, so you are looking for a piece of code inside your module, that would somehow do this? (is this what you are talking about ???).

**Module Chrome** though, isn't something that is controlled on the module level, rather than it is a Template Feature. It defines a "layout"/html markup of a module position on a template, it happens outside of the module and it's not something that any module instance knows anything about it or care. Module Chrome isn't something that a module developer would have to think.

**Programatically**, it can be set to a default choice, for each module position, but this is done by the template when module positions are defined in it.

This is how it's done:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-1" style="none" />
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-2" style="xhtml" />
```

Something that of course can be overriden by the end-user when creating and assigning any module on any position.

Comment: Thanks, so it looks like this is not possible.  I think for any template it would be fine but modules are supposed to work for any template.  And this is an admin one, so ideally I am thinking about Isis.  I guess I would need to update Isis, but then how do I do that for each and every install?  And I don't want to do it for all items in the cpanel position just this one.

Comment: @Eoin - I updated my answer. Now it does make sense your question.

Comment: yes it makes sense (for someone who knows nothing) but nothing appear to occur in the back end the module is still installed as usual with no position and the standard module chrome.

Comment: @Eoin I don't know what you have done, the above is a draft postflight function which you have to adjust to your module and implement inside your install.php mod_yourModuleInstallerScript Class. At first try to echo something from inside the postflight function and see if it gets printed after your installation. Do also note that with the $type condition check, the code below it will run only on first installation and not on update.

Comment: and you also have to declare your install.php in your module's xml file something like <scriptfile>install.php</scriptfile>

Comment: @Eoin - updated my question - including a link to J! Documentation about adding install script to a module.

Comment: Thanks for all your help you're an encyclopedia of Joomla! great answer.  If I could up-vote it more I would do :)